# AWS X-Ray monthly trace threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-xray

I would like to set a monthly threshold on the number of traces collected by AWS X-Ray (mainly to avoid unexpected expenses).

It seems that sampling rules enable us to limit the trace ingestion but they use one second window.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-sampling.html

But setting a limit on the number of traces per seconds might cause me to loose some important traces. Basically the one second window seems unreasonably narrow and I would rather set the limits for a whole month.

1. Is there any way to achieve that?
2. If not, does anyone know the reason why AWS does not enable that?

(Update)
Answer by Lei Wang confirms that it is not possible and speculates about the possible reasons (see the post for details).

Interestingly log analytics workspaces in azure have this functionality so it should likely not be impossible to add something similar to AWS X-Ray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XRay right now supports 2 basic sampling behaviors:

1. ratio
2. limit the sampled per second

These 2 can be used together in `or` relationship to become the 3rd behavior: ratio + reservoir. For example, 1/s reservoir + 5% ration. Means sample at least 1 trace / second, then if the throughput is over 1/second, sample additional 5%.

The reason XRay does not support more sampling behavior like you mentioned `limit per month` I guess because technically it is not easy to implement and not sure whether it is a common user requirement. Because XRay is not able to guarantee customer would not reboot application within 1 month. Even user say his application would never reboot. XRay SDK still need communication mechanism to calculate the total traces across fleet. So, the only possible workaround is user application keeps tracking how many traces have been in XRay backend in total by periodically query.